# is there any use of NSArray or NSString in swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3, nsstring, nsarray

I just start learning swift and I never used NSString and NSArray in swift 3.1
but when i say WWDC 2014 swift video there apple used these so plz could someone explain us or if there any reference document to learn it plz share that

Comment: 2014: What version of Swift was that ? An very old one, no ? In Swift 3, prefers Swift Array, Dictionary, Strings, etc.

Comment: Important detail: NSString and NSArray are not in Swift itself, they are in the Foundation framework. You can use all Foundation features with Swift, but you should use Swift's own types in your own code instead of NSString and NSArray when possible.

Answer (score 0):

YES. There is actually. 
When you want value type use Array and when you want reference type use NSArray. For all the impacts that are there when using the two you can go through [this](https://swiftwithsadiq.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/class-vs-struct-in-swift/).

But use it judiciously when there is a strong case to use reference type i.e NSArray or NSString.